# Solving the Monty Hall problem using Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, monty-hall

Let $A_{i}$ be the event "the prize is in th $i$ - th door". Let's consider $P(A_{1} | A_{2}^c)$, that is, the probability that the prize is in the first door, given that it is not in the second door (Monty Hall has revealed us the door). Using Bayes' theorem, we get

$$P(A_{1} | A_{2}^c) = \dfrac{P(A_{2}^c | A_{1}) \cdot P(A_{1})}{P(A_{2}^c)}.$$

The probability that the prize is *not* in the second door, given that it is in the first one is clearly 1. Hence, $P(A_{2}^c | A_{1}) = 1$. Because the prize is put at random, $P(A_{1}) = \dfrac{1}{3}$. Finally, the probability that the prize is not in the second door is $\dfrac{2}{3}$. In consecuence, $P(A_{2}^c) = \dfrac{2}{3}$. Substituing the values, we get

$$P(A_{1} | A_{2}^c) = \dfrac{1}{2}.$$

However, from what I have found, the correct answer is $\dfrac{1}{3}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The conditional probability is not $A_2^c$ it is $A_2^c$ along with the condition that Monty chose to open that door. If $A_1$ is true, Monty could have opened $A_3.$ That is why an equivalent paradox from the game of bridge is sometimes called “the principle of restricted choice.” The case when Monty had no choice what door to open is more likely.

Comment: That’s also why it is important that Monty has to follow the rule: Monty must open one empty door from the two unchosen doors, and offer the option to switch. If Monty opens a random door, and only gives a chance to switch if that random door is empty, then you’d be correct that the probability is $\frac12.$

Comment: This website explains how to solve this problem using Bayes' Theorem: https://brilliant.org/wiki/monty-hall-problem/